# Merging of two arrays

Tags: c

I wan to merge two arrays but this code is not giving me the desired output.Can anyone plz point out the error?I applied this code on my own but cannot logically find any mistake.

```
 int main()
    int i,n,m;
    int size;
    printf(" enter the size of 1st array");
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d element is ",i);
        scanf(" %d",&a[i]);
}
        printf(" enter the size of 2nd array");
    scanf(" %d",&m);
    int b[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d element is ",i);
        scanf(" %d",&a[i]);

    }
        printf(" the merged array is"); 


    int k;
    int arr[size];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=a[i];

    }
    size=m+n;
    for(i=n,k=0;i<size  && k<m;i++,k++)
    {

        arr[i]=b[k];

    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d",arr[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: In this statement  `int arr[size];`, `size` is used before initializing. May you can try moving `size=m+n;` before `int arr[size];`.

Comment: sorry but still getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your program.

When reading second array, you should read it in array `b` but you are reading it in array `a`:

```
scanf(" %d",&a[i]);
             ^
```

This should be

```
scanf(" %d",&b[i]);
```

Other problem is variable `size` is used before initializing:

```
int arr[size];
```

Instead, you should first initialize `size` with `m+n` and then use it:

```
size=m+n;
int arr[size];
```

---

Also, you don't need to give white space in `scanf()` with format specifier `%d`:

```
scanf(" %d",&n);
       ^ this space is not needed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now it is running perfectly.